# Invoking REST API in Angular returns null first, but then gets called again and returns correct data

Tags: angular, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm developing an Angular project that retrieves data from a DB constructed using an .NET Core Web API with Entity Framework. I have developed the Web API to do all the basic REST APIs, and they seem to work when I work in Postman. 
However, I notice that Angular is behaving a bit weirdly.

Basically, as I was debugging, I noticed that the function I defined to execute the REST API was being called twice, first when I actually told it to be called, and once seemingly out of nowhere. The first time it is called it returns null, but returns the correct data the second time. This causes my code to break, as the data I retrieve from the REST API will be used to populate some fields that I have on my page.

The way I am storing the data is by having a model Object (let's call it "Student") inside my service. The current workaround I have is to actually assign this Student object when I actually call the API. While this produces the correct end result, the program does not behave the way I want it to. The flow of how the program works currently is as such:

1. Login page shows up
2. User enters ID
3. Alert shows up directing user to enter a valid ID or create a new Student with that ID (this shouldn't happen)
4. Page redirects to a form page with correct data

To begin, here is an abridged version of my service class:

```
export class StudentServiceService {
  formData: Student;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  getStudentByNSEPId(StudentId: string) {
    try {
      this.http.get(this.rootURL + 'Student/getStudentByStudentID/' + StudentId).toPromise().then(
        (res: Student[]) => {
          this.populateForm(res[0]);
          return res[0];
        },
        error => {
          return null;
        }
      );
      return null;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Get failed');
    }
  }
  populateForm(student: Student) {
    this.formData = student;
  }
}
```

The function I used in my component to actually submit the data is:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.valid) {
      let student: Student = this.service.getStudentByStudentId(this.studentIDLoginInput);
      if (student !== null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/entry']);
        debugger;
        // this.populateForm(student);
      }
      else {
        alert('Please either enter a valid NSEP ID or create a new student with the ID ' + this.studentIDLoginInput);
        this.router.navigate(['/entry']);
      }
      debugger;
    } else {
      alert('Please enter an ID');
    }
  }
```

Note: `studentIdLoginInput` is just the variable I am using two-way-binding with from my HTML.

Please let me know of any other code snippets that would be helpful.

Is this expected behavior? I feel like there is just a slight change that I would need to make here to have the REST APIs actually work when called initially, rather than after they're called.

Comment: You should really finish Angular tutorial before anything else. Http returns an Observable which is asynchronous. You should return Observables and subscribe to them. Don't map them to Promises. Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I used subscribe before, as I had whenever I used http elsewhere. However, I get the same behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry, it looks like I structured my code wrongly. I actually made this mistake a few weeks ago, but forgot. I'm still getting a hang of Angular, so sorry for the pointless question. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Comment: Thank you for your responses and patience :)